# Redirecting All Requests to Index.html

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect all requests made to my website to index.html if the request aren't made from AJAX. Apart from just redirecting, I would like to append the request URI as a get parameter to index.html, for example if someone visits `http://example.com/something.html`, the person should be redirected to `http://example.com/?origin=something.html`. To achieve this, I have the following code in a .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Requested-With} !=XMLHttpRequest
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-REQUESTED-WITH} !^(XMLHttpRequest)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index.html)?$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^/.*.html$ /index.html?origin=%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]
```

However, it does not redirect any requests as expected. I'm on Apache/2.4.33, Ubuntu 16.04. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you configure rewriting in .htaccess context, the path the RewriteRule matches on _never_ starts with a `/`, because that has been stripped of at that point already.

Comment: @CBroe You mean my `RewriteRule` should look like `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /index.html?origin=%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CBroe pointed out, I was facing the issue because the context of .htaccess has the initial `/` removed from `%{REQUEST_URI}` that is usually the conditional part of `RewriteRule`. Therefore, the solution was only having to change the `RewriteRule` to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ /index.html?origin=%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]
```